# Showing connection of cross-ratio and Schwarzian derivative for a holomorphic function $f$.

Tags: complex-analysis, cross-ratio

> For some holomorphic function $f$ show that 
>   $$\lim_{t\to0} \frac{cr(f(ta),f(tb),f(tc),f(td))-cr(a,b,c,d)}{t^2cr(a,b,c,d)}=\frac{(a-b)(c-d)}{6}S(f)(0)$$
>   where $cr(a,b,c,d)$ is the cross-ratio of four points in $\Bbb C$ and $S(f)$ is the Schwarzian derivative of $f$.

I am unsure on how to really make any progress after inserting the definition of the cross-ratio and turning it all into one fraction (rather than fractions in a fraction). I tried working from the other side but made even less progress, since I don't even know how I am supposed to get the factor $(a-b)(c-d)$ in there, since this is nowhere in the fraction.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is holomorphic, it has a series expansion
$$ f(z) = z_0 + z_1 z + z_2 z^2 + z_3 z^3 + O(z^4) \tag{1}$$
at $\;z=0$.
Using the definition of the Schwarzian, we get that
$$ R_0 := S(f)(0) = 6(z_1z_3-z_2^2)/z_1^2. \tag{2} $$
Using cross-ratio we get that
$$ cr_1:=\textrm{cr}(a,b,c,d)=
 \frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(a-d)(b-c)} \tag{3} $$
and let
$$ cr_2:=\textrm{cr}(f(ta),f(tb),f(tc),f(td)).
 \tag{4} $$
Using algebra on power series and simplifying gives us
$$ \frac{cr_2-cr_1}{t^2cr_1} = 
\frac16 R_0(a-b)(c-d) + O(t).
 \tag{5} $$
Taking limits as $t\to0$ gives us the identity.

What we mean by using algebra is to use equation $(1)$
and replace $f(z)$ with a truncated power series. For
exmaple, we have the following result:
$$ \frac{f(ta)\!-\!f(tc)}{t(a-c)} \!=\!
   z_1 \!+\! (a\!+\!c)z_2t + (a^2\!+\!ac\!+\!c^2)z_3t^2 
\!+\! O(t^3). \tag{6}$$
The rest of the calculations are similar, keeping
only the power series terms which we can determine.